# How a symbolic matrix can be Hermitian

Tags: matrix

How can I learn *Mathematica* that the `ham` matrix with symbolic elements is `Hermitian`?

```
Block[{jz \[Element] Reals, j \[Element] Reals, b \[Element] Reals}, 
      HermitianMatrixQ[{{(jz + 2 b)/2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, (-jz + 2 b)/2, j, 
        0}, {0, j, (-jz - 2 b)/2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, (jz - 2 b)/2}}]]
```

Comment: `Block`, `With`, `Module` etc. must take assignments, not predicates or assumptions.

Comment: `Block` is used to declare (and assign values to) local variables. You should tell domain restrictions to `HermitianMatrixQ`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the `SameTest` option and `Simplify`:

```
HermitianMatrixQ[{
  {(jz + 2 b)/2, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, (-jz + 2 b)/2, j, 0},
  {0, j, (-jz - 2 b)/2, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, (jz - 2 b)/2}
  }, SameTest -> (Simplify[#1 - #2, {jz ∈ Reals, j ∈ Reals, b ∈ Reals}] == 0 &)]

(* result: True *)
```

This option is [covered in the documentation](https://wolfram.com/xid/0ywpa67efp9v-63zf1y)